# Symfony forms: error mapping of fields with custom property_path

Tags: forms, validation, symfony-forms, symfony

I have a problem with error mapping of fields defined with a custom property path. My situation is as follows:

The form type:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(
            'aField',
            TextType::class,
            ['property_path' => 'anObject.aProperty']
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([ 'data_class' => FormData::class ]);
    }
}
```

The form data class:

```
class FormData
{
    /**
     * @var MyObject
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    public $anObject;
}
```

The form data nested object:

```
class MyObject
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $aProperty;

    // NOTE: this object has other properties that are not mapped by my form and I'm not listing here for the sake of brevity.
}
```

My problem is the following: when a violation occurs at `aProperty`, the violation path is `data.anObject.aProperty` so the error is not automatically mapped to the `aField` form field. I understand this is correct from a "vanilla" validation standpoint, but I would expect some sort of translation layer at the form level that adjusts the mapping based on the `property_path` attribute in order to attach form errors to the correct fields. I tried juggling with the `error_mapping` option but turns out it's not what it's made for.

Am I wrong in expecting this as a "default" behavior? Would you think this might be considered as a bug, or at least a feature request worth requesting? Did somebody have to do with a similar situation and found a solution?

Comment: What is `aField`? Is it mapping `anObject` or not? It seems not clear.

Comment: as you see in the classes below, `aField` is mapped to `aProperty` of `anObject`, which itself is a property of the form data class.

Comment: is mapped ... where? I don't see any `aField` in your classes :) that's what I mean

Comment: that's the point: I'm mapping it by using the `property_path` form field option

Comment: In that case, as I've suggested, you should use a `DataTransformer` or a `embeddedForm`. This is by design, I suppose.

Comment: Could you please post the `error_mapping` configuration you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Questionnaire has property $user

User has a OneToMany relationship with Residency.

I had to submit some data to user's first Residency in Questionnaire type, so i included field 'residency' with property_path to the first user's residency (user.residencies[0]). After that, i had to append options of root form (QuestionnaireType) with error_mapping to tell, that residencies errors should go to 'residency' type ('user.residencies' => 'residency')

Just in case - **Questionnaire entity doesn't have property "residency"**.

There is my solution:

```
<?php

class QuestionnaireType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('residency', 'residency', [
                'data_class' => Residency::class,
                'property_path' => "user.residencies[0]",
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'questionnaire_form';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => Questionnaire::class,
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'error_mapping' => [
                    'user.residencies' => 'residency'
                ],
            )
        );
    }
}
```